# access Arcgis server from R

Tags: r, post, token, arcgis, httr

I'm trying to convert an access token creation from python to R in order to access an arcgis server. The Python script works very well :

```
token_resp = requests.request(
        method="POST",
        url="https://mywgisweb/arcgis1/tokens/", 
        data={
            "f": "json",
            "request": "getToken",
            "expiration": "60",
            "username": "test_user",
            "password": "pass",
        }
        ).json()

access_token = token_resp["token"]
access_token_expiry = token_resp["expires"]
```

In R I'm trying the `httr` package in R :

```
library(httr)

token_resp <- POST(
  url = "https://mywgisweb/arcgis1/tokens/",
  body = list(
    request = "gettoken",
    username = "test_user",
    password = "pass"
  ),
  content_type = "application/json"
)
```

then I have :

```
token_resp
Response [https://mywgisweb/arcgis1/tokens/]
  Date: 2023-08-23 15:21
  Status: 200
  Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
  Size: 265 B
```

But I can not extract the token from here !

I tried :

```
content(token_resp, "text")
[1] "Invalid request <br>Usage: https://mywgisweb/arcgis/tokens?request=gettoken&username=username&password=password&<br>Usage: https://mywgisweb/arcgis/tokens/generateToken?username=username&password=password&<br>Usage: https://mywgisweb/arcgis/tokens/gettoken.html<br>"
```

Also used `content_type = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` in the post request and used the `content(token_resp, "parsed")` I end up with the same error !